# PHP Function as body Error: Message body empty

Tags: function, email, phpmailer

I have success sent email with phpmailer and text as body. But now I want to display function as body email and I getting error. In other condition echo isiemail() looks good

```
$mail->isHTML(true);
// Konten/isi email
$mailContent = isiemail();
$mail->Body = $mailContent;
// Kirim email
if(!$mail->send()){
    echo 'Pesan tidak dapat dikirim.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}else{
    echo 'Pesan telah terkirim';
```

Comment: Show the output from `var_dump($mailContent)` after you’ve set it.

Comment: the value of var_dump($mailContent) is NULL

Comment: Well there's your answer. Figure out why your `isiemail()` function returns `null`.